# HTTP file plugin for IntelliJ?

Tags: rest, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

Is there anything like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client for IntelliJ? I think I saw this on twitter, but I don't find anything in the plugin repo or via google. My basic requirement is that `.http` files are treated special so that I can send requests specified in the file from the IDE.

Comment: Are you looking for https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/09/editor-based-rest-client/ ?

Comment: Yes, that is it. I used the wrong keywords to search. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/09/editor-based-rest-client/) for details. The feature will be available starting from IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 version.